# I use Image_Picker Plugins to pick image and video. but The Problem is The Opening Camera is Normal it doesn't have any Effects Feature?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Image_Picker Plugins to pick images and videos. from Camera and Gallery. The Problem is  The Opening Camera is Just a Normal Camera it doesn't have any Effects,
I use this code to Capture images and video. but The opening Camera is Just a Normal one, what I want is a Camera Like Tiktok which has Editing, Flip, speed, Timer, Effects, and More  Features.
I want both Camera and Recording Camera to have the above Features

```
here is my code.
 CaptureImageWithCamera() async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    final image = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      imageQuality: 50,
      maxHeight: 680,
      maxWidth: 970,
    );
    setState(() {
      if (image != null) {
        _imageFile = File(image.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

here how i pick video

```
_pickVideoFromCamera() async {
    File video = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
     _cameraVideo = video; 
    _cameraVideoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_cameraVideo)..initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() { });
      _cameraVideoPlayerController.play();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own code with effects with [camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera).

You must add your features to camera widget and get result and use it as you need it.

Update one :

You can use this plugin for add filters and effects :

https://pub.dev/packages/photofilters

Comment: Could  you Please Share with me any link which is work under Camera Effect